# Multiple Integral calculus exercise

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

Could someone explain me that change of variables on the integral sign? .Perhaps some theorem is escaping me or I am not getting it. Thanks for reading.

Comment: The order of integration has been switched. Check the differentials.

Comment: Did you try to draw the triangular domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. The domain of integration is the triangle
$$\{(x,y): y\in [0,1], x\in [y,1]\}=
\{(x,y): 0\leq y\leq x\leq 1\}=\{(x,y): x\in [0,1], y\in [0,x]\}.$$